# UIButton as subview on complicated UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

In my app i implement really complicated control, which based on `ARScrollViewEnhancer`. I need it for displaying multiple pages of `UIScrollView`. So this is my code for `UIScrollView`:

```
dateScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(28, 0, dateLabelMaxSize, 45)];
dateScroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
dateScroll.clipsToBounds = NO;
dateScroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
dateScroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
dateScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(dateLabelMaxSize*[dayArray count], 45);
```

I use `dateScroll.clipsToBounds = NO;` for displaying pages out of frame. This is code for `ARScrollViewEnhancer`:

```
ARScrollViewEnhancer *backForDate = [[ARScrollViewEnhancer alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, self.view.frame.size.width, 45)];
[backForDate addSubview:dateScroll];
backForDate._scrollView = dateScroll;
[self.view addSubview:backForDate];
```

Then i added subviews for `UIScrollView`. This is `UILabels` and `UIButtons`.

```
for (int i=0;i<[dayArray count];i++){

    UILabel *dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3+dateLabelMaxSize*i, 5, dateLabelMaxSize, 40)];
    dateLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    dateLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    dateLabel.text = @"some text...";
    [dateScroll addSubview:dateLabel];


    UIButton *dateButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    //dateButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    dateButton.frame = CGRectMake(3+dateLabelMaxSize*i, 5, dateLabelMaxSize-10, 40);
    dateButton.tag = i;
    [dateButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dateTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [dateScroll addSubview:dateButton];
}
```

And method for buttons:

```
-(void)dateTapped:(UIButton*)button{
    NSLog(@"%i",button.tag);
}
```

So, buttons not worked (( why?
Thnx.

**UPD.**

hitTest methode code. Was:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
        return _scrollView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Now:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *scrv = _scrollView;
    UIView *superView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (superView == self)
    {
        CGPoint scrollViewpoint = [_scrollView convertPoint:point fromView:self];

        for(UIView *view in _scrollView.subviews) {
            if(CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, scrollViewpoint)) {
                return view;
            }
        }

        return scrv;
    }

    return superView;
}
```

Comment: You have to set the ContentSize of your scroll view

Comment: @Mutawe i did it. add to my code in question. dateScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(dateLabelMaxSize*[dayArray count], 45);

Answer (score 1):

If you also copy the hitTest method in your custom control, it is the one causing the issue because it always return the scroll view instead of the button.

You need to return the correct subviews instead of always returning the subview, something like this:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
    UIView *scrv = self.scrollView;
    UIView *superView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (superView == self)
    {
        CGPoint scrollViewpoint = [self.scrollView convertPoint:point fromView:self];
        for(UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
            if(CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, scrollViewpoint)) {
                return view;
            }
        }
        return scrv;
    }
    return superView;
}
```

Comment: @EugeneTrapeznikov do you implement the hitTest? Can you edit your question to include the hitTest method?

Comment: @EugeneTrapeznikov can you elaborate more what does not work? Try to set breakpoints too in the hitTest and see whether the UIButton is returned from the hitTest.